# What is the association bonus?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

I was looking at my reputation timeline graph and I wondered about a spike of 164 rep I'm sure wasn't there before. Upon looking it up, I found an entry *+100 : association bonus*

[image]

Does anyone know what this is awarded for?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You got +100 for associating your account with your account on another SE site. This is for getting users to connect their accounts in the network.

That's why you often can see users seeming to start with 101 rep, not just 1.

Comment: You need to have at least 200 rep on one site to get the bonus on all sites. Related questions on [metase]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56461/why-do-we-get-rep-points-on-associating-our-accounts, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56506/award-account-association-bonus-automatically-upon-reaching-200-rep.

Comment: Will this bonus stack up? (i.e. 200 rep on 2 sites will means 2*100 association bonus for accounts on other SE sites)

Comment: @freak_warrior 100 on each site account, not stacking.